# On special type of p-group of class two

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group of class two and  $T$ be the minimal set of generators of $G$. Also let
$G=\langle a, b, x_{1},..., x_{n}\rangle$ such that $|a|=|b|=p^n$,  $a,b\in T$,   $x_{1},..., x_{n}\in (T\cap Z(G))$ and $|x_{i}|< p^n$ for $i$.
Then do can say that

$$G=\langle a, b\rangle\times \langle x_{1},...,x_{n}\rangle?$$
 I think this is true.

Thank you

Comment: I think you meant $H\subseteq \langle T\cap Z(G)\rangle$ instead of $H\subseteq T\cap Z(G)$.

Comment: @QuangHoang: OK. I edited it and omit $H$. Now is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is NO. The best one can get is that $G$ is a quotient of $\langle a,b\rangle \times \langle x_1,\cdots, x_n\rangle$, that is $G$ is a central product of the two subgroups.

Comment: Yes, the answer to the question asked is no, but I think you could make it correct by changing $T$. For example, if $n=3$, $[a,b]=c$ with $|c|=p^3$, and $x_1^p=c^{p^2}$, then $|x_1|=p^2$, but you could replace $x_1$ by $x_1' := x_1c^{-p}$, and then $|x_1'|=p$.

Comment: elham: Not really, in @DerekHolt's example, one can make $|c|=p^6$, and $x_1^{p^2}=c^{p^4}$. Then you would need some $x_1'$ which has order $p^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: PLease guide me that how can make it correct by changing $T$?